# Accessing Mutation Result in Angular Apollo Graphql

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am new to Graphql and I am using the Apollo client with Angular 7.

I have a mutation in the server that I am using for authentication.This mutation generates returns an access token and a refresh token:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class LoginTokenAuthGQL extends Apollo.Mutation<
  LoginTokenAuth.Mutation,
  LoginTokenAuth.Variables
> {
  document: any = gql`
    mutation loginTokenAuth($input: LoginAuthInput!) {
      loginTokenAuth(input: $input) {
        accessToken
        refreshToken
      }
    }
  `;
}
```

I am running this mutation in my sign-in component like this:

```
 onLoginSubmit() {
    const email = this.loginForm.controls['userEmail'].value;
    const password = this.loginForm.controls['userPassword'].value;

    console.log('Sending mutation with', email, password);

    this.loginGQL.mutate({
      input: {
        email,
        password,
        userType: AuthUserType.Crm
      }
    }).pipe(
      map((response) => response.data )
    ).subscribe(
      (output: LoginTokenAuth.Mutation) => {
        console.log('Access token', output.loginTokenAuth.accessToken);
        console.log('Refresh token', output.loginTokenAuth.refreshToken);

        console.log(this.apollo.getClient().cache);
      },
      ((error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
      })
    );
  }
```

Once I get the access token I will need to add it as header on my requests.

From what I read from the Apollo Client all results from queries and mutations are cached locally in the client. But it is not clear to me how can I access them and add it to the apollo-link.

To be more clear I would like to do this in my Graphql module:

```
const http = httpLink.create({uri: '/graphql'});

const auth = setContext((_, { headers }) => {

  // get the authentication token from the cache
  const token = ???

  if (!token) {
    return {};
  } else {
    return {
      headers: headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    };
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even [official docs of Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication.html) suggest you store this token as usually - to localStorage.

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql',
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Comment: Well according to Auth0 I should either store the token only in memory or add it to a cookie: https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens. If I want to store it in memory, I think I will have to manually add it to my local state then. This way I can query it later. However I am not sure if this doesn't seem to be a good practice.